# disable iframe in fckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, fckeditor

My html contains an iframe which refering to an external page. When it loads to fckeditor, it shows that external page also. Is there anyway to prevent this.

-Arun

Answer (score 0):

FCKeditor doesn't include such option, it was added recently to CKEditor (remember that FCKeditor is no longer supported)